# How to send encoded query (or string) to php from jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sparql

I have a string that represent a sparql query to send to php server. Into that query I have a part that it is encoded by the jquery method encodedURIComponent.

The problem is that if I make a print of the string from the php side I see that the encoded part of the string is arrived decoded, and that is why I get the 500 internal Server Error that is caused by the following error, with the result that the sending of the query is denied.

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EasyRdf_Exception' with message 'HTTP request for SPARQL query failed: Error 400: Encountered " "<" "< "" at line 2, column 948. Was expecting one of: <IRIref> ... <PNAME_NS> ... <PNAME_LN> ... <BLANK_NODE_LABEL> ... <VAR1> ... <VAR2> ... "true" ... "false" ... <INTEGER> ... <DECIMAL> ... <DOUBLE> ... <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ... <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ... <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ... <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ... <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ... <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ... <STRING_LITERAL1> ... <STRING_LITERAL2> ... <STRING_LITERAL_LONG1> ... <STRING_LITERAL_LONG2> ... "(" ... <NIL> ... "}" ... "[" ... <ANON> ... Fuseki - version 2.0.0 (Build date: 2015-03-08T09:49:20+0000) ' in C:\xamp_workbench\xampp\htdocs\heisenberg\easyrdflib\EasyRdf\Sparql\Client.php:284 Stack trace: #0 C:\xamp_workbench\xampp\htdocs\heisenberg\easyrdflib\EasyRdf\Sparql\Client.php(174): EasyRdf_Sparql_Client->request('update', 'PREFIX oa: <htt... in C:\xamp_workbench\xampp\htdocs\heisenberg\easyrdflib\EasyRdf\Sparql\Client.php on line 284
```

this is the method that sends the query to php

```
function sendQuery(jsonDaInviare) {
console.log(jsonDaInviare);

 $.ajax({
   //headers: {'Content-Type': 'contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",'},
    url: 'php/AutomaticScrape.php',
    data: "annotazioniDoc="+jsonDaInviare,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        arrayAnnotazioni = [];
        json = "";
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Errore nel mandare il json al server");
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

this is the php method that recives the query from jquery

```
if(isset($_POST['annotazioniDoc'])){
// here I find that the encoded part of the string arrives decoded
echo $_POST['annotazioniDoc'];
// this is commented because the query returns me that error
// $jsonDaMandare = $GLOBALS['sparql']->update($json);
```

}

To be more precise this is the part of the string that is encoded:

```
<http://rivista-statistica.unibo.it/article/view/4601_cited_A.M.%20MATHAI%20…Linear%20Algebra%20and%20its%20Applications%20396%2C%20pp.%20317-328._ver1>
```

Therefore this is how it is returned from php:

```
<http://rivista-statistica.unibo.it/article/view/4601_cited_A.M. MATHAI (2005), A pathway to matrix - variate gamma and normal densities, Linear Algebra and its Applications 396, pp. 317-328._ver1>de here
```

**EDIT**

I'm resolved whit this:

```
$.post( "php/AutomaticScrape.php", { annotazioniDoc: jsonDaInviare }, function() { 
        // do stuff
```

})

Comment: Can you provide the code that sends the data and that receives the data?

Comment: I provided what you asked me

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(jsonDaInviare);`?

Comment: The content of jsonDaInviare is a string that represent the query (that contains the encoded part that I want to mantain)

Comment: I was just trying to make sure that it's really encoded :)

Comment: It looks like SPARQL is expecting `XML` formatted input.

Comment: Yes, in fact the xml isnt' respected because there is a subject of query that contain white space. The problem is that the php call return decoded subject of query that contains white space.

Check the edit of the original post please :)

Comment: why not encoding it within php ? [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)